# Trying to hide/show divs on radio button clicks

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to hide and show different divs depending on which radio button people click on.

- Jquery is loading fine, I've tried putting an alert on page load.
- Very similar code, selector methods etc have worked on a page in the same directory with the same includes on the same server

The input box code is:

```
            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="input_sandwich_choice" value="Panini">Panini</label>
            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="input_sandwich_choice" value="Sandwich">Sandwich</label>
            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="input_sandwich_choice" value="Baguette">Baguette</label>
```

The divs are:

```
        <div id="div_bread_options" class="collapse span3"> <!--2.2-->
            <h4>Which bread would you like?</h4>
            <label class="radio"><input id="id_option_bread_white" type="radio" name="input_bread_choice" value="white">White</label>
            <label class="radio"><input id="id_option_bread_brown" type="radio" name="input_bread_choice" value="brown">Brown</label>
            <label class="radio"><input id="id_option_bread_granary" type="radio" name="input_bread_choice" value="granary">Granary</label>
            <label class="radio"><input hidden id="id_option_bread_none" type="radio" name="input_bread_choice" value=""></label>
        </div> <!--2.2-->

        <div id="div_butter_options" class="collapse span3"> <!--2.3-->
            <h4>Would you like butter?</h4>
            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="id_option_butter_yes" name="input_butter_choice" value="Yes">Yes</label>
            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="id_option_butter_no" name="input_butter_choice" value="No">No</label>
            <label class="radio"><input hidden type="radio" id="id_option_butter_none" name="input_butter_choice" value=""></label>
        </div> <!--2.3-->
```

And finally the Jquery is:

```
<script>

    $("input[name=input_sandwich_choice]").click(function() {
    var checkedValue = $("input[name='input_sandwich_choice']:checked").val();
    console.log(checkedValue);
    if (checkedValue == "Panini") {
        $("#div_bread_options").collapse('hide');
        $("#div_butter_options").collapse('show');
    } else if (checkedValue == "Sandwich") {
        $("#div_bread_options").collapse('show');
        $("#div_butter_options").collapse('hide');
    } else if (checkedValue == "Baguette") {
        $("#div_bread_options").collapse('show');
        $("#div_butter_options").collapse('hide');
    } else {
        alert("Oops.");
    }
});​​
    </script>
```

Just can't figure why that doesn't work... Any help much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `alert` does not mean you have loaded jquery... what you get in the console?

Comment: And you placed that script after the HTML, otherwise you'll need a DOM ready handler !

Comment: try this instead : `if(window.jQuery){alert("jquery loaded");}`

Comment: jyc do I just put that right at the start of <script>?  And it's within the HTML tags adeneo... what's a DOM ready handler, is that $(document).ready(function... etc?

Comment: @user2536206 yes that it is the right one... and you can put that anywhere in the script. but jquery has to be loaded first

Comment: mmm I have put that in, I've also tried:

 $(document).ready(function(){
 if(window.jQuery){alert("jquery loaded");}
    });

and I'm not getting an alert...

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the console? What errors do you get?

Comment: try adding an `else` and `alert` something, if does `alert` that means that jquery is not loaded. but if does not alert is for sure is not loaded, also you can open the console in google chrome to see errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you have something like this in your header

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

the you can use this anywhere after this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input[name=input_sandwich_choice]").click(function() {
    var checkedValue = $("input[name='input_sandwich_choice']:checked").val();
    console.log(checkedValue);
    if (checkedValue == "Panini") {
        $("#div_bread_options").collapse('hide');
        $("#div_butter_options").collapse('show');
    } else if (checkedValue == "Sandwich") {
        $("#div_bread_options").collapse('show');
        $("#div_butter_options").collapse('hide');
    } else if (checkedValue == "Baguette") {
        $("#div_bread_options").collapse('show');
        $("#div_butter_options").collapse('hide');
    } else {
         console.log("Oops.");
    }
});​​
    });
```

also i would recommend you to use `console.log` instead of `alert`, this way your script does not stop each time to alert something.

so the final should look something like this::::

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="input_sandwich_choice" value="Panini">Panini</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="input_sandwich_choice" value="Sandwich">Sandwich</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="input_sandwich_choice" value="Baguette">Baguette</label>

<div id="div_bread_options" class="collapse span3"> <!--2.2-->
            <h4>Which bread would you like?</h4>
            <label class="radio"><input id="id_option_bread_white" type="radio" name="input_bread_choice" value="white">White</label>
            <label class="radio"><input id="id_option_bread_brown" type="radio" name="input_bread_choice" value="brown">Brown</label>
            <label class="radio"><input id="id_option_bread_granary" type="radio" name="input_bread_choice" value="granary">Granary</label>
            <label class="radio"><input hidden id="id_option_bread_none" type="radio" name="input_bread_choice" value=""></label>
        </div> <!--2.2-->

        <div id="div_butter_options" class="collapse span3"> <!--2.3-->
            <h4>Would you like butter?</h4>
            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="id_option_butter_yes" name="input_butter_choice" value="Yes">Yes</label>
            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="id_option_butter_no" name="input_butter_choice" value="No">No</label>
            <label class="radio"><input hidden type="radio" id="id_option_butter_none" name="input_butter_choice" value=""></label>
        </div> <!--2.3-->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input[name=input_sandwich_choice]").click(function() {
    var checkedValue = $("input[name='input_sandwich_choice']:checked").val();
    console.log(checkedValue);
    if (checkedValue == "Panini") {
        $("#div_bread_options").collapse('hide');
        $("#div_butter_options").collapse('show');
    } else if (checkedValue == "Sandwich") {
        $("#div_bread_options").collapse('show');
        $("#div_butter_options").collapse('hide');
    } else if (checkedValue == "Baguette") {
        $("#div_bread_options").collapse('show');
        $("#div_butter_options").collapse('hide');
    } else {
         console.log("Oops.");
    }
});​​
    });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I access the console is Chrome? 

I've also added the else and nothing happened so eseems likely jquery isn't working, but it's strange because I had it working in another file in the same directory using the same include

Comment: that it is odd... right `click` on the page, `inspect element` a new window will show, select console there from the tabs

Comment: that's going to come in handy, thanks!  Is it possible I could PM you the URL and you could take a look please?

Comment: yeah sure just send it to my email, is listed in my profile.. also check the last update. should help in this matter..

Comment: you can delete that i can help you in 20 min.. add me on google talk... or mail me to jycr753@gmail.com

Comment: but you have this on the end of the script `;â€‹â€‹` and also if you going to use html5 as such make sure your doc is html5 other wise this will create an error

Answer (score 0):

Common issue actually - Your script is run before the browser has loaded the whole document; essentially the body doesn't exist yet.

Simplest solution is to contain any code that modifies the document inside of a 'document ready' function. JQuery makes this simple.

```
$(function() {
  // document manipulation code here
});
```

Note that if your script happens to be below the < body > tag, then I may have jumped the gun, and there could be another issue in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this but I have tried using a document ready... surely this is just run every time the buttons are clicked rather than at load?

Comment: The question being "what buttons"? You're right that the main body of your code wouldn't run yet - but JQuery has to have buttons there, in order to give them event listeners. For instance, if you added another button to the page after it had loaded, it would not have the same event listeners as the others.

Comment: Ahh! That's good to know thanks a lot.  Didn't fix it unfortunately anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

Use latest jQuery library from google CDN

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='input_sandwich_choice']").on("click",function() {
        var checkedValue = $("input[name='input_sandwich_choice']:checked").val();
        alert(checkedValue);
        if(checkedValue=="Panini") {
            $("#div_bread_options").collapse('hide');
            $("#div_butter_options").collapse('show');
        }

        else if(checkedValue=="Sandwich") {
            $("#div_bread_options").collapse('show');
            $("#div_butter_options").collapse('hide');
        }

        else if(checkedValue=="Baguette") {
            $("#div_bread_options").collapse('show');
            $("#div_butter_options").collapse('hide');
        }

        else {
            alert("Oops.");
        }
  });​​
});​​
</script>
```